# Phonegap installation problems-resource folder doesnt exist

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to install phonegap. I've installed node.js, java jdk, phonegap, apache-ant, i added all path variables to PATH: jdk, ant-apache, android-sdk,platform-tools,tools 
and it still doesnt work:

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova platform add android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova platform add android'
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android'...
cp: no such file or directory: C:\Windows\System32\test\icon.png


Running command: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat

Buildfile: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\build.xml


-set-mode-check:


-set-debug-files:


-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.5

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Jenya\Downloads\r\sdk


-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp

  [gettype] Project Type: Application


-set-debug-mode:


-debug-obfuscation-check:


-pre-build:


-build-setup:

[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...


[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2

[gettarget] API level:        19

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\ant-build

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\ant-build\re
s

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\ant-build\rs
Obj


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\ant-build\rs
Libs


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\ant-gen


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\ant-build\cl
asses


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\ant-build\de
xedLibs


     [echo] ----------


     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...


[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------

[dependency] Ordered libraries:


[dependency]

[dependency] ------------------

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...


nodeps:


-set-mode-check:


-set-debug-files:


-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.5

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Jenya\Downloads\r\sdk

-setup:


     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp

  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library


-set-debug-mode:


-debug-obfuscation-check:


-pre-build:

-build-setup:

[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...

[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2

[gettarget] API level:        19

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\r
es


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\l
ibs


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\a
nt-build


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\a
nt-build\res


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\a
nt-build\rsObj


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\a
nt-build\rsLibs


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\a
nt-gen


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\a
nt-build\classes


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\CordovaLib\a
nt-build\dexedLibs


     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...

[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency] No Libraries

[dependency]

[dependency] ------------------


-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [aapt] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\androi
d\CordovaLib\res' does not exist


BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Jenya\Downloads\r\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occu
rred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Jenya\Downloads\r\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error occu
rred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Jenya\Downloads\r\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 1 second


C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Windows\System32\
test\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen

Error: C:\Windows\System32\test\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command faile
d with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Jenya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ph
onegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:1
35:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

What should i do t make it work?

ok.the problem solved. It seems to me that it's related to some permissions issues on C drive, i created new project on D and it worked.

Comment: Write `cordova -v` to check current version. Then move to some other path maybe in `D:\ ` directory. Type `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`. Then `cd hello`. After that `cordova platform add android`. **See what happens and which step gives you error**.

Comment: for some reason cordova -v is not working

Comment: just type `cordova`, seems like cordova is not in globals path variables.

Comment: how can i add this varible path? where is it usually placed?
I thought i installed phonegap not cordova

Comment: ok.the problem solved. It seems to me that it's related to some permissions issues on C drive, i created new project on D and it worked.

Comment: bravo!!, we killed the beast ;)