# IONIC - ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Windows\System32\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\res' does not exist

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cross-platform

I am trying to run an `Ionic` app in an `Android` device. I have added `Android` as a platform and when trying to build, it gives me the error.

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Windows\System32\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\res' does not exist    

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

The 'res' folder is in the given location although the error log sugegst otherwise.

For more information and the log, please refer the attachments.

Can somebody help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: remove android platform and build again

Comment: @Anuj Gupta : Tried a couple of times but this error happens after that too.

Comment: Try to create other project and then move your www folder and install plugins and then try

Comment: @Anuj Gupta : I did. I also created a cordova project and tried to build the app, but this same error came.

Comment: check permission .refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657534/phonegap-installation-problems-resource-folder-doesnt-exist

Comment: @Anuj Gupta : Thanks for your time. I just figured out that my Android sdk path is not set properly and I re did the steps and now it is okay.

Comment: That is great .Close issue and flag answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can solve this problem by installing Android SDK Platform 24 and Android 
SDK Platform 23  and Sources for Android 23.